Calculations of python code not returning expected results
import pandas as pd
data = {
"Close": [47758.25, 47767.45, 47809.15, 47796.55, 47793.1, 47794.05, 47786.15, 47781.05, 47770.55, 47746.1,
47754.3, 47733.2, 47727.25, 47744.65, 47737.45, 47753.65, 47749.85, 47745.35, 47740.4, 47765.75,
47770.4, 47769.9],
"upper": [47785.04421, 47781.79402, 47778.54383, 47775.29364, 47772.04346, 47768.79327, 47765.54308, 47762.2929,
47759.04271, 47755.79252, 47752.54234, 47749.29215, 47746.04196, 47742.79178, 47739.54159, 47736.2914,
47733.04121, 47818.8, 47817.04957, 47815.29915, 47813.54872, 47811.7983],
"slope_ph": [3.250186916, 3.250186916, 3.250186916, 3.250186916, 3.250186916, 3.250186916, 3.250186916,
3.250186916, 3.250186916, 3.250186916, 3.250186916, 3.250186916, 3.250186916, 3.250186916,
3.250186916, 3.250186916, 3.250186916, 1.750426169, 1.750426169, 1.750426169, 1.750426169,
1.750426169],
"ph": [False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data['upos'] = 0
length = 14
for i in range(len(data)):
if data.loc[i, 'ph'] and i + length < len(data):  # if ph and not exceeding index limit
    data.loc[i + length, 'upos'] = 0
elif i > 0:
    if data.loc[i, 'Close'] > data.loc[i, 'upper'] - (data.loc[i, 'slope_ph'] * length):
        data.loc[i, 'upos'] = 1
    else:
        data.loc[i, 'upos'] = data.loc[i - 1, 'upos']

print(data)
data is dataframe having columns Close, ph, slope_ph and upper
I am trying to get results based on below conditions :

When ph = True, reset the value of 14th row of upos to 0
Else check if Close > upper - slope_ph * length -- if yes set value of upos to 1
if 2nd point is not true, retain previous value of upos

In other words trying to achieve same results like below pine code :
var upos = 0
upos := ph ? 0 : close > upper - slope_ph * length ? 1 : upos
Tried to update the code multiple time, but each time code keeps updating same row of upos to 0 where ph = True instead of row 14th of upos

Try to create an MRE and show it as properly formatted text in the question. Here especially add code to create a sample data df.

Thanks, I tried to make it as simple as possible

You didn't apply data we can work with (nobody here likes to copy numbers from an image for someone else's problem).
I assume (from reading your code) that in your third condition where you write "old value", you mean the value from the row before and not the initial value of the cell.
Now this is a bit tricky because the line before is subject to the changes that occur on execution and that's enough that the line before will be 1 so all the following values on the column will be 1 as well so my code is using the value of the column in the row before from a copy of the column before the change (which is 0 as initiated).
    df['upos'] = df.apply(lambda x, x_len=df['ph'].shift(length), x_old=df['upos'].shift(1): 
                   1 if x_len[x.name] else 
                   1 if x['Close'] > x['upper'] - x['slope_ph'] * length else 
                   x_old[x.name], 
                   axis=1).astype(int)

